# Webpack: Injecting variables into static service-worker.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm writing PWA app. I was using default Service Worker from template that I'm using (Vue.js PWA template), but now I have decided to write my own from the scratch. I have placed it (`service-worker.js`) into `static` folder, because I want to have static name for it - I don't want to change name each time (build).

In this particular Service Worker I want to use package `name` and `version`, so that I can nicely generate cache ID.

So I want to achieve something like this:

**./package.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "my.app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
}
```

**./static/service-worker.js**:

```js
var CACHE_ID = 'PACKAGE_NAME-vPACKAGE_VERSION';
// ...
```

**./build/service-worker.js**:

```js
var CACHE_ID = 'my.app-v1.0.0';
```

The `./build/service-worker.js` shows what I want to achieve.

I have tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader with below configuration:

```json
{
  test: /service-worker\.js$/,
  loader: 'string-replace-loader',
  options: {
    multiple: [
      {
        search: 'PACKAGE_NAME',
        replace: packageConfig.name
      },
      {
        search: 'PACKAGE_VERSION',
        replace: packageConfig.version
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But as I understand files placed in `static` are not modules (am I right?), so those are not checked by `module.rules`.

I would be greatful for help and/or guidence how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finnaly got it. I have used `copy-webkit-plugin` and it's possibility to transform:

```
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: 'static/service-worker.js',
        to: './service-worker.js',
        transform (content) {
          var parsed = content.toString();
          var transformation = [
            {
              search: 'PACKAGE_NAME',
              replace: packageConfig.name
            },
            {
              search: 'PACKAGE_VERSION',
              replace: packageConfig.version
            }
          ];

          for(var i = 0; i < transformation.length; i++) {
            parsed = parsed.replace(transformation[i].search, transformation[i].replace);
          }

          return Buffer.from(parsed, 'utf8');
        }
      }
    ])
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Modules

Modules are placed in `node_modules`. `src` is your source folder, where you should keep only this files you're not going to use in `production` mode.

Also remember that modules is nothing more than just a JavaScript code like libraries; set of functions. If you move your *.js files from `node_modules` to `src` — this still will by modules.

I can not really understand why would you like to use `string-replace-loader` as it has nothing to do with your question.

> Loader allows to perform replacements in a way String.prototype.replace() does (loader uses it internally). It means that if you want to replace all occurrences, you should use RegExp-like string in options.search with g flag in options.flags, etc.

And from `String.prototype.replace()` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

Or did I misunderstood you?

## [Worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader)

But if I understood you correctly — there's actually a loader for workers.

```
$ npm install worker-loader --save-dev
```